# Multivariate (Multi-responce) for negative binomial (GLM) in R

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, negative-binomial-distribution, multivariate-regression

I developed a multivariate linear regression using lm() function in R. However, I am having trouble coding a Multivariate model in R for glm(), especially for the negative binomial. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction as I have been wondering for weeks.
Thanks,

Comment: Just to be clear on what you mean by multivariate: multiple factors/covariates in the model (provided e.g. by glm.nb in MASS) or multiple correlated negative binomial outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

If you used lm, you probably mean multivariable, i.e. multiple predictors, not multiple responses.

In that case, you have to use the glm.nb package. It comes with examples that are easy to follow.

If you do mean multivariate (multiple response variables), I don't think there's an easy way to do this in R. I would use Bugs or Jags. Define gamma distributed latent variables lambda1, lambda2 and lambda3, and now model y1~dpois(lambda1+lambda3), y2~dpois(lambda2+lambda3)